# Trying To Create A Small Mail App - Getting Lag When Checking For Mail And Typing New Message

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

In the application I am working on, I have built functionality that allows users to send 'mini' emails to each other.  Basically, I simply output the contents to a MySQL DB, and then poll the DB to check if there are any entries into the DB for that user with a Read=False status.  I also have a form that shows an Inbox (and outbox) of all messages which constantly refreshes when open.  My problem that I am finding is that when a user types detail into the message body field, there is a constant lag every xx when the software checks the DB for new messages.

I know I haven't set this up correctly and I'm therefore after the best method of building this routine.

**MainForm:** Has a timer that fires every 5 seconds that runs a query against the DB and returns an integer value `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Mail WHERE is_read = 0 AND recipient = " & Current_User.Id`

**ShowMessagesForm:** When opened, makes an initial query to the DB and returns all messages for the current user into a DataTable.  This then clears the Listview control and re-populates using the DataTable.

```
Private Sub LoadMessages()
    Dim QueryString As String

    Try
        'Populate Inbox
        lsvMail.Items.Clear()
        If InboxDataTable IsNot Nothing Then InboxDataTable.Clear()
        QueryString = "SELECT m.id, Recipient.Display_Name AS Recipient, Sender.Display_Name AS Sender, m.subject, m.body, m.call_id, m.is_read, m.replied, m.followup, m.deleted, m.sent_deleted, m.sent " & _
                        "FROM Mail m " & _
                        "LEFT JOIN Clients Sender ON m.Sender = Sender.id " & _
                        "LEFT JOIN Clients Recipient ON m.Recipient = Recipient.id " & _
                        "WHERE m.Recipient = " & Current_User.Id & " AND m.deleted = 0 " & _
                        "ORDER BY m.Sent DESC"
        InboxDataTable = db_Connection.ReturnData(QueryString)
        If InboxDataTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            For x = 0 To (InboxDataTable.Rows.Count - 1)
                Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(InboxDataTable.Rows(x)("replied").ToString)
                lvi.SubItems.Add(InboxDataTable.Rows(x)("sender").ToString)

                If CBool(InboxDataTable.Rows(x)("is_read")) = True Then
                    lvi.Font = RegularFont
                Else
                    lvi.Font = BoldFont
                End If

                If CBool(InboxDataTable.Rows(x)("followup")) = True Then
                    lvi.ForeColor = Color.Red
                Else
                    lvi.ForeColor = Color.Black
                End If

                lvi.SubItems.Add(DecryptData(InboxDataTable.Rows(x)("subject").ToString))
                lvi.SubItems.Add(InboxDataTable.Rows(x)("sent").ToString)
                lvi.SubItems.Add(InboxDataTable.Rows(x)("followup").ToString)
                lvi.Name = InboxDataTable.Rows(x)("id").ToString
                lsvMail.Items.Add(lvi)
            Next
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        CreateLog("Module: frmShowMessages: LoadMailMessages()" & vbNewLine & "Exception Error: " & ex.Message)
        MsgBox("Exception Error: " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Module: frmShowMessages: LoadMailMessages()")
    End Try
End Sub
```

There is also a Timer control on this form that fires every 5 seconds which runs the above Sub Routine everytime.

**ComposeMessageForm:** Simply contains a subject textbox and a body richtextbox control.

When I enter text into the richtextbox, I am finding that everytime the timer triggers on the ShowMessagesForm, it creates a lag in typing on my form.

So basically, I guess I am asking what is the best method of creating a small application that constantly checks for messages?  It needs to check on the main form to see if the user has any new messages, and then constantly refresh the Inbox listview in case any messages arrive whilst the form is open.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your query returns *every* email that the user has received.  Even though you are only interested in new emails that you haven't seen before.  Yeah, that's going to suck mud after a while.  A simple fix is to improve your WHERE clause so it only selects emails that were sent with a date that's higher than the last one you have in your list.  Makes the query as well as updating the listview a *lot* faster.

Comment: @HansPassant That is because I pull all the sent items as well for a separate listview.  But I guess I can use the same theory for both Inbox and Outbox items.

Answer (score 0):

You must use multiple threads for such a case. That way the polling logic is implemented in a separate thread and does not affect the rest of the application.

Comment: nrip, thanks for the reply.  Could you be so kind as to provide more detail please.  I understand how to create threads, but where would I implement them and what part of the code would be part of the tread?  I don't require full examples, just a basic example would be great.  Thanks

Comment: Okay, I have added a message check routine on a separate thread AND changed my query to only poll for the latest items (as suggested by Hans), however, I still get a slight lag when typing text into a new message.  I am now at a loss with this.